# HTML5 assumed Mime Types

Tags: html, mime-types

I've been experimenting with HTML5 lately, and found it of interest that when adding javascript to pages, you no longer need to declare the scripting language as you did previously. It assumes that javascript is being used unless you specifically declare another language with a mime type.

OLD:
    `<script type="text/javascript"> // Do Something </script>`

NEW:
    `<script> // Do Something </script>`

What I'm wondering is if HTML5 assumes other mime types as well - for including css or favicons, etc.

Anyone know where I could find more info on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html looks like it sums them all up fairly well.

Comment: Great! Thanks for this. There is a ton of things i'll be able to shorten up with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can also drop the type attribute in a stylesheet link. Just use:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

without `type="text/css"`.

[Dive into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) by Mark Pilgrim contains a [chapter](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html) covering this sort of subject.